# Could not install mysql-server inside docker container

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, dockerfile

I want to configure a container with MySQL, thereafter I will add a java application to the container. But, I could not install MySQL-server inside the container.

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]
```

I got the following error:

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>   2015/09/01 13:17:36 The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken] returned a non-zero code: 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's probably happening is the `apt-get install` is asking for input, and failing. What happens if you just run those commands interactively in the base container? e.g. launch a shell with `docker run -ti --rm ubuntu:latest /bin/bash`

One thing you can try is to use the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable, e.g.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install mysql-server
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I got the same error in both cases; however in the first case, it asked me to enter the password as well.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/tutumcloud/mysql/blob/master/5.5/Dockerfile - I've amended my answer to use the -q flag which should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the official mysql docker image. When running that you have to provide the root password as an environment variable during the docker run command. That would be better.